# I need help about SDL 2

Tags: c, sdl-2

I have a problem when I run my prog : "prog.exe just stopped working".

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *screen; // even with SDL2, we can still bring ancient code back
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Surface *image;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); // init video

    // create the window like normal
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Example", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0);

    // but instead of creating a renderer, we can draw directly to the screen
    screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    // let's just show some classic code for reference
    SDL_FillRect(image, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(image->format, 0, 255, 0));
    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, NULL); // blit it to the screen
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);

    // this works just like SDL_Flip() in SDL 1.2
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    // show image for 2 seconds
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

// gcc src/main.c -o bin/prog -I include -L lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Comment: I don't know SDL, but I don't see where you initialize `image`.

Comment: Please give feedback about your results when acting on Eugenes hint.

Comment: Use a debugger (gdb comes with MinGW which is what I assume you're using since you're compiling with gcc) to see where the crash happens. Add the `-g` flag when compiling, and then `gdb prog.exe` to start the debugger, and use the `run` command in the debugger to actually run the program.

Comment: Windows will report your application is 'Not Responding' because you are not processing SDL events, and in turn, windows messages. You should have an event loop. See `SDL_WaitEvent` and related functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eugene Sh. pointed out your surface isn't initialized

You need to create the surface someway, either by loading an IMG or using [SDL_CreateRGBSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface). Add this before calling SDL_FillRect and now your code shows a green screen.

```
image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, width, height, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```